# How to get number of idle and "active" connections in Go?

Tags: go

Assuming I have a regular HTTP Server in Go. How can I get the currently idle and active TCP connections?

```
httpServer := &http.Server{
    Handler: newHandler123(),
}

l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err = httpServer.Serve(l)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: you can use linux terminal to grep active  connections if your server is on linux operating system

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a type to count the number open connections in response to server [connection state](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ConnState) changes:

```
type ConnectionWatcher struct {
    n int64
}

// OnStateChange records open connections in response to connection
// state changes. Set net/http Server.ConnState to this method
// as value.
func (cw *ConnectionWatcher) OnStateChange(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
    switch state {
    case http.StateNew:
        cw.Add(1)
    case http.StateHijacked, http.StateClosed:
        cw.Add(-1)
    }
}

// Count returns the number of connections at the time
// the call.    
func (cw *ConnectionWatcher) Count() int {
    return int(atomic.LoadInt64(&cw.n))
}

// Add adds c to the number of active connections. 
func (cw *ConnectionWatcher) Add(c int64) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&cw.n, c)
}
```

Configure the net.Server to use the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values):

```
var cw ConnectionWatcher
s := &http.Server{
   ConnState: cw.OnStateChange
}
```

Start the server using [ListenAndServe](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.ListenAndServe), [Serve](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.Serve) or the TLS variants of these methods.

Call `cw.Count()` to get the number of open connections.

[Run it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KuvuX98XqkX).

This code does not monitor connections [hijacked](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Hijacker) from the net/http server.  Most notably, WebSocket connections are hijacked from the server.
To monitor WebSocket connections, the application should call `cw.Add(1)` on successful upgrade to the WebSocket protocol and `cw.Add(-1)` after closing the WebSocket connection.

Comment: This seems to work fine on my mac used for development. But when I put this in linux ubuntu production this counter is between zero and one. How is this possible when there is about hundreds of websocket connections alive? Anyway, great and simple solution.

Comment: @KrešimirPrcela  The code in the answer monitors connections managed by the net/http server.  WebSocket connections are hijacked from the net/http server.  The application must write code to monitor hijacked connections.